# Find the limit, if it exists, of $x_n = \frac{2^n}{4 + 7^n} + (-1)^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Find the limit if it exists. Justify all steps.
>   $$x_n = \frac{2^n}{4+7^n} + (-1)^n.$$

Intuitively I know its limit doesn't exists because of $(-1)^n$. But I want to prove it rigorously. Can anyone help me prove why it diverges?

Comment: Are you able to show $\frac{2^n}{4 + 7^n}$ converges and $(-1)^n$ diverges?

Comment: What do you mean its limit? Yea I get you’re probably questioning the limit as $\mathrm{x}(n)$ goes to something, just need a bit more details and I can try to help. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Lemma**

If a sequence $(a_{n})_{n=m}^{\infty}$ of real numbers converges to $L$, then every subsequence converges to $L$ as well.

**Proof**

If $b_{n}$ is a subsequence of $a_{n}$, then $b_{n} = a_{f(n)}$, where $f:\textbf{N}\rightarrow\textbf{N}$ is strictly increasing.

Based on the definition of limit, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a natural number $N\geq m$ such that
\begin{align*}
n\geq N \Longrightarrow |a_{n} - L|\leq\varepsilon
\end{align*}
Since $f(n) \geq n$, we conclude that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $N\geq m$ such that
\begin{align*}
f(n) \geq n \geq N \Longrightarrow |a_{f(n)} - L| = |b_{n} - L| \leq \varepsilon
\end{align*}
and we are done.

**Solution**

Consider the sequence $\displaystyle x_{n} = \frac{2^{n}}{4+7^{n}} + (-1)^{n}$. Thus we have that $x_{2k}\to 1$ and $x_{2k+1}\to -1$.

Therefore the proposed sequence does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that difference of two converging sequences converge and assume at first that $\{x_n\}$ is convergent, can you subtract something to show a contradiction?